# Is it possible to be completely immune to SQL Injection?

Tags: php, mysql

Also, are there more ways to break into a site? if so, can you be completely immune to those too?

Thanks.

Comment: Voted to close as "Not Constructive"; the *short* answers to these questions are, "No, it isn't. Yes, there are. No, it isn't."

Comment: Yes, there are many more ways a website's data can be compromised. If an outdated, vulnerable service is running on the machine it can be exploited and, depending on the severity of the flaw, data can be compromised. Just one of many possibilities.

Comment: Is this the right room for an argument?

Comment: Not using a database is a good way of preventing SQL injection :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the only safe way to answer a question so vague is to say NO! You cannot be immune since there is always a way, even if you have to be Ethan Hunt to figure it out.

Even if you can't be affected by injection, you are not safe from other ways to attack a database - since you didn't exclude things like host admins, corrupt people, standard links to mysql admin and guessing passwords, etc.

You can be paranoid and go through all the ropes to be as secure as possible, but with good backups and logs you can revert if something tears you up on the odd occasion. Of course, such a lackadaisical statement loses its value as the scale of your site grows. But for the everyday guy - at least the guy at the level where he is asking this kind of question - you're probably safe with basic provisions. Most frameworks have input escaping to help prevent badness, but it only goes so far.

Just don't get into banking software until you know how to answer this question on your own.

Comment: Man, sucks to be you. lol. Spend 4 minutes writing an answer and the question gets closed immediately :P

Answer (score 1):

Your question is unclear, but here it goes:

**Is it completely possible to be completely immune to SQL injection?**
Sure, in the sense that a "Hello World" application can be completely immune from such an attack. In general, the more opportunities you have for user input, dynamic content, etc, the more likely it is that there *could be* a vulnerability. However, many modern PHP frameworks like Yii make it easier to avoid such attacks through some built-in validation procedure templates, etc. It's kind of like *is it possible to avoid all gunshot attacks*? Sure, stay indoors and lock yourself in a dark, panic room. But an informed person can generally avoid gunshot attacks by staying away from shady neighborhoods, not drawing attention to their person, etc.

Edit: There's a better analogy out there, I'm sure.